# Stored procedure in neo4j 3.0

Tags: java, stored-procedures, neo4j

I'm using neo4j 3.0 on Windows and I try to use stored procedures new feature.

I have built the apoc.jar from [github sources](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures).
This jar is copied into plugins repository (**C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community\plugins**)

I get a Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureNotFound error when I try to call any apoc stored procedure from neo4j browser.

[image: ProcedureNotFound error]

I tried to follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897634/there-is-no-procedure-with-the-name-apoc-help-registered-for-this-database-ins), but dbms configuration parameter does not work for me...

Comment: By the way I confirm that on Unix machine it works perfectly well

Comment: It seems like a know issue on Neo4j Desktop. https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/wiki/Neo4j-3.0-changelog

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same problem but then I came to know that I was copying the jar file in the wrong directory. I created a plugins folder in the following directory and copied the jar file in plugins folder then everything started to work.

Path: `C:\Users\<username>\Documents\Neo4j\default.graphdb`

This is the path where your neo4j instance is residing. While starting neo4j you can see the path of DB for which you are starting Neo4j.

Answer (score 0):

The commenter is right, the Desktop version has these issues for sure. I ran into the same problem on windows but I've switched to the zipped version and everything is working correctly, I was able to deploy the apoc procedures and it is running.