# Neo4J: Expand node with children childrens (Performance)

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

I thought this would be very easy, because i have a typical graph use case: Expand a node.

This is easy if there are no additional requirements:

```
MATCH (s:Entity)-[]-(dest) WHERE s._id = 'xxx'
RETURN dest
```

**Problem Nr.1:** sometimes there are many children so i want to limit the return count!

```
MATCH (s:Entity)-[]-(dest) WHERE s._id = 'xxx'
RETURN dest
LIMIT 100
```

**Additional requirement:** Return all children ids of the children childrens!

```
MATCH (s:Entity)-[]-(dest) WHERE s._id = 'xxx'
WITH collect(dest) as childrenSource
LIMIT 100
MATCH (childrenSource)-[]-(childDestination)
RETURN childrenSource as expandNode, collect(childDestination) as childrenIds
LIMIT 100
```

**Problem 2:** The limits are in the wrong place, because collect already did the collection before the limit.

Possible solution:

```
MATCH (s:Entity)-[]-(dest) WHERE s._id = 'xxx'
WITH collect(dest)[..100] as childrenSource
LIMIT 100
MATCH (childrenSource)-[]-(childDestination)
RETURN childrenSource as expandNode, collect(childDestination)[..100] as childrenIds
```

But i dont thinks this is a performant solution. Because it takes quite a lot of time

**Exact Problem description:** If i have 1 node with 1000 children and each child has another 1000 children i want to execute a query which returns 100 children with 100 child ids

```
-------------------------------------------------
| node 1   | child id 1_1,....   child id 1_100 |
| node 2   | child id 2_1,....   child id 2_100 |
| ...      | ...                                |
| node 100 | child id 100_1,.. child id 100_100 |
-------------------------------------------------
```

**Other solution:** i do a simple expand for the node. and than i call an expand on each child node. But doing 101 queries instead of 1 query sounds not too performant either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT

As usual, [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_running_cypher_fragments) to the rescue. Using apoc.cypher.run(), you can use LIMIT within a subquery, which lazy-load the expansion up to your limit.

```
MATCH (s:Entity)-[]-(dest) WHERE s._id = 'xxx'
WITH dest
LIMIT 100
CALL apoc.cypher.run('
 MATCH (dest)-[]-(childDestination)
 RETURN childDestination LIMIT 100
 ', {dest:dest}) YIELD value
RETURN dest as expandNode, COLLECT(value.childDestination) as childrenIds
```

Comment: this would be a good possibility. but i think the lib is not compatible with the latest neo4j version?
I am using Neo4j 3.1.1 CE
i tried:
- apoc 3.0.8.4: Server didnt start anymore
- apoc 3.1.0.3 & 3.1.0.2: this adds only a single new function: apoc.schema.assert

Comment: Others have mentioned something's going on here. Are you on Windows?

Comment: yes i am using neo4j on windows (the community edition)

Comment: In a different question, another Windows user had problems getting APOC to work. They mentioned after following [these instructions](https://indexoutofrange.com/Neo4jStoredProceduresWindows/) they were able to get it working.

Comment: i use the solution with the APOC library. Thanks a lot

Comment: for the installation, see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42286508/apoc-is-only-partially-installing-its-extension-in-neo4j-one-procedure

Answer (score -2):

Using `cypher` would help you

```
MATCH (entity1)-[rel]-(entity2) WHERE entity1.title = "something"
WITH entity2
LIMIT 100
CALL apoc.cypher.run('
 MATCH (entity2)-[]-(childDestination)
 RETURN childDestination 
 LIMIT 100
 ', {entity2:entity2}) YIELD value
RETURN entity2 as expandNode, COLLECT(value.childDestination) as childrenId
```

Comment: or
MATCH p = (entity1) - [*1..3] -> (entity2)  WHERE entity1.title = "something" RETURN p