# How to install apoc for neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

According to https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/, one only needs to download the binary jar from  http://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/releases/3.1.0.3 to place into the folder "Neo4j CE 3.1.1\plugins".

I did so. However, I was unable to call "call apoc.help("apoc")" from the http://localhost:7474/browser/.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you installed neo4j using a Windows or Mac installer (which most people do), and not from a zip or tar file, then the `plugins` folder should be in your database folder, not in your neo4j installation folder.

Here is a related answer with a little more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42357481/974731.

Comment: I did use an installer. But there was on "plugins" folder in the default.graphdb folder.

Comment: I just added the plugins folder into the default.graphdb folder. It works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 25):

I'm using Red Hat Linux specifically Oracle-7 and here is how I got it working

1. Download the [`apoc-<version>.jar`](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/releases/download/3.5.0.3/apoc-3.5.0.3-all.jar) into the `/var/lib/neo4j/plugins` directory
2. `chown neo4j:neo4j apoc-<version>.jar`
3. `chmod 755 apoc-<version>.jar`
4. Open the neo4j.conf at `/etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf` and replace the line `#dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=apoc.coll.*,apoc.load.*` with `dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=apoc.coll.*,apoc.load.*,apoc.*` and save it.
5. Restart the Neo4j service by issuing the command `systemctl restart neo4j`

Note: Make sure that you have the right version of apoc jar downloaded. I'm using the `neo4j version 3.5.5` and the apoc jar version I'm using is `apoc-3.5.0.3-all.jar`. Alos make sure that you have the `dbms.directories.plugins=/var/lib/neo4j/plugins` uncommented in the `/etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf`

Comment: after that you can check the installation with `call apoc.help('apoc')`.I used 'match...' and thought it's not working.

Answer (score 3):

according to documentation:
there are 2 types of APOC

1. APOC Core
2. APOC Full

first one included in the installation folder($NEO4J_HOME/labs) and for the second one u need to download it("Make sure that the first two version numbers match between Neo4j and APOC").

if u want to go with APOC Core just copy $NEO4J_HOME/labs/apoc-...jar file to the $NEO4J_HOME/plugins

and for APOC Full download the package then put it into $NEO4J_HOME/plugins directory. finally restart.

linux command for APOC Core assuming neo4j installed in /var/lib/neo4j:

```
sudo cp /var/lib/neo4j/labs/apoc-4.3.0.3-core.jar /var/lib/neo4j/plugins/
sudo chown neo4j:neo4j /var/lib/neo4j/plugins/apoc-4.3.0.3-core.jar
sudo systemctl restart neo4j
```