# Compare data of two nodes of different labels in Neo4j with some property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
Match(csav:CSAVHierarchy) with csav


Match(cx:CXCustomerHierarchy) with cx

    Optional Match(csav)-[:CSAVCustomerHasChild]->(csa:CSAVHierarchy) where csa._type='CXCustomer' OR csa._type='CXCustomerBU'
    Optional Match(cx)-[:CXCustomerHasChild]->(cxc:CXCustomerHierarchy) where cxc._type='CXCustomer' OR  cxc._type='CXCustomerBU' 
    return
    CASE
    WHEN csa.ssid = cxc.ssid and csa.elementLabel = cxc.elementLabel
    THEN "yes"
    ELSE "No"  END As result
```

with this query its giving cartesian issue and  i want to carry forward both the nodes data for further use.

where I m lacking?

Comment: What if there are different values for the same property?

Comment: Currently I  am just looking to merge the nodes who have same ids

Comment: What @Raj is asking, is this: if 2 nodes with the same `ssid` have different `name` values, how do you pick the `name` value to use in the merged node?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Apoc` plugin (see https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures):

```
Match(n:Person{ssid:"1234"}) with collect(n) as nodes CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes(nodes) YIELD node RETURN node
```

Comment: I am using commnunity edition for testing , how to install apoc procedure there

Comment: You can place the jar (see https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/releases) in the plugins folder

Comment: You can run `call apoc.help("apoc")` after restarting? If not, have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42741433/5785085

Answer (score 1):

This query may do what you want. It returns the unique `cxc` and `csa` pairs that pass all your tests.

```
MATCH (csa:CSAVHierarchy)
WHERE
  (:CSAVHierarchy)-[:CSAVCustomerHasChild]->(csa) AND
  csa._type='CXCustomer' OR csa._type='CXCustomerBU'
MATCH (cxc:CXCustomerHierarchy)
WHERE
  (:CXCustomerHierarchy)-[:CXCustomerHasChild]->(cxc) AND
  csa.ssid = cxc.ssid AND
  csa.elementLabel = cxc.elementLabel AND
  (cxc._type='CXCustomer' OR  cxc._type='CXCustomerBU')
RETURN cxc, csa
```

For better performance, you should also create [indexes](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/) on `:CSAVHierarchy(_type)` and `:CXCustomerHierarchy(_type)`.

Answer (score 0):

This the solution I came up with

```
MATCH(cxc:CXCustomerHierarchy)-[:_properties]->(auditnode)-->(spoke)
 where cxc._type='CXCustomer' OR  cxc._type='CXCustomerBU' AND spoke.start_date <= 1554272198875 <= spoke.end_date AND spoke.status = "Confirmed"
 with cxc
 OPTIONAL MATCH (cxc)<-[r:CXCustomerHasChild]-(parent) with cxc
 MATCH(csav:CSAVHierarchy)-[:_properties]->(auditnode)-->(spoke) with cxc,csav
 where csav._type='CXCustomer' OR  csav._type='CXCustomerBU' AND spoke.start_date <= 1554272198875 <= spoke.end_date AND spoke.status = "Confirmed"
 OPTIONAL MATCH (csav)<-[r:CSAVCustomerHasChild]-(parent) with csav,cxc
return 
CASE
WHEN csav.sourceSystemId <> cxc.sourceSystemId , csav.elementLabel <> cxc.elementLabel
THEN csav.elementLabel
ELSE "SIMILAR DATA "  END As result
```