# Can't get APOC to work on Neo4j Community Edition google cloud instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I created a Neo4j Community Edition instance on google cloud from the marketplace and when I tested it from my local application I got the following error: `Error: Unknown function 'apoc.cypher.runFirstColumn' (...)`

I did some digging and found out that APOC was not installed on the cloud instance. I tried to install it via an ssh connection but I can't seem to get it to work.

I am pretty sure that APOC should come preinstalled. Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> An important thing to note about cloud version of neo4j is that you
> should not modify the /etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf file directly, but rather
> modify /etc/neo4j/neo4j.template. The system service that restarts
> neo4j calls a shell script called pre-neo4j.sh.

https://neo4j.com/developer/neo4j-cloud-vms/

I modified the neo4j.conf file directly. Oops... Leaving this here in case someone else does this.

(edit)
This was not the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56227465/15118442 this helped fix the problem. Btw, apoc still does not come preinstalled with CGP instance from the marketplace. You have to install apoc yourself. And for initialization I recommend the above stackoverflow link.

Comment: BTW I figured out that apoc does come with neo4j in GCP. It is located at /var/lib/neo4j/labs. Just mv that to /var/lib/neo4j/plugins and restart neo4j. The above changes to neo4j.conf is still necessary though.