# neo4j APOC does not work locally on Win10

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

**edit:** Using Neo4j Community Edition 3.2.1.

I successfully installed [APOC](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures) on my remote machine (debian) and it's working just fine.
However locally (Win10) I can't seem to get it to work.

What I did:

- pasted the jar into the `plugins` folder
- tried to run some APOC stuff via neo4j browser and REST/Postman as well and I got: `Unknown function 'apoc.convert.fromJsonList'`

What I tried to fix it so far:

- Restarted Neo4j
- Restarted the machine
- Reinstalled Java

Comment: Are you using the community edition exe-installation ? That has known issues. The zip-installation should work fine though !

Comment: @Tom Geudens please see my edit above. atm trying to find resources on installing APOC via zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: create a `plugins` folder in the `default.graphdb` folder and put APOC there.
Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42357481/974731.

In my opinion this should be at least hinted at in the readme of the APOC git repo.