# How to access the browser interface to install APOC in Neo4J?

Tags: browser, neo4j, interface, neo4j-apoc

Not knowing how to verify if APOC is installed with my Neo4J database – which is however very unlikely – I started it and opened the browser at http://localhost:7474/browser/
But the interface only displays 6 icons for information in the left bar : Database, Favorites, Help...This does not correspond to the interface that would be necessary to install APOC : https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures
How can I access this one ?

Comment: How are you running Neo4j? From Neo4j Desktop or Docker or?

Answer (score 0):

The APOC installation is not accessible via browser. It can be installed via Neo4j desktop app OR by copying the jar file in your installation directory.

After you download the APOC jar file, copy it in neo4j/plugins directory then restart your database. See the detailed steps here:

```
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42286508/apoc-is-only-partially-installing-its-extension-in-neo4j-one-procedure/42357481#42357481
```

Comment: I followed the instructions in this article , https://guptaparas.in/neo4j-virtual-machine/ (same as neaGaze’s answer in the one jose bacoy recommended above) , but the first step *me@USER...Q4E: /var/lib/neo4j/plugins$ wget https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/releases/download/4.2.0.2/apoc-4.2.0.2-all.jar* ends with *apoc-4.2.0.2-all.jar: Permission denied Cannot write to ‘apoc-4.2.0.2-all.jar’ (Success)* And if I still try to move on to the second one, *chown neo4j:neo4j apoc-4.2.0.2-all.jar*, I get *chown: cannot access 'apoc-4.2.0.2-all.jar': No such file or directory*