# Neo4j APOC configuration not working on the CentOS 7

Tags: reactjs, neo4j, cypher, centos7, neo4j-apoc

I have deployed a ReactJS application with neo4j database on `CentOS 7` server. Neo4j version is 4.4.2. The application also uses apoc library. So i added `apoc-4.4.0.1-all.jar` file to the `/var/lib/neo4j/plugins` directory on the server. Then i did following-

1. `chown neo4j:neo4j apoc-4.4.0.1-all.jar`
2. `chmod 755 apoc-4.4.0.1-all.jar`
3. Modify `/etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf` file to

   - `dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=apoc.coll.*,apoc.load.*,apoc.*`
   - `dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*`
   - uncomment `dbms.directories.plugins=/var/lib/neo4j/plugins`
4. `systemctl restart neo4j`

After deploying the project, when i open the application on the browser and insert some values in a form, it shows following error-

```
Unknown function 'apoc.map.submap' (line 3, column 14 (offset: 56)) " WHERE apoc.map.submap(properties(n), keys(obj), [], false) = obj" ^
```

Did i miss anything in apoc configuration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ownership of `/var/lib/neo4j/data` folder has to be `neo4j`, not `root`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the plugin directory from: /var/lib/neo4j/plugins to /var/lib/neo4j/graph.db/plugins directory then restart the neo4j server. You need to create the folder if not found.

If you install neo4j using an installer rather than download/untar/unzip a zipped/tar file; then neo4j server is looking at the apoc under default.graphdb folder

related: [APOC is only partially installing its extension in neo4j (one procedure)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42286508/apoc-is-only-partially-installing-its-extension-in-neo4j-one-procedure)

Comment: you mean plugin directory should be /var/lib/neo4j/graph.db/ ?

Comment: pls use this instead: /var/lib/neo4j/graph.db/plugins

Comment: i used RPM package to install neo4j on CentOS 7 server.

Comment: and what should be the access permission of the newly created files ?

Comment: i created new folders /var/lib/neo4j/graph.db/plugins and copied apoc-4.4.0.1-all.jar file into it. then updated dbms.directories.plugins=/var/lib/neo4j/graph.db/plugins in neo4j.conf file. then restarted with sudo service neo4j restart . but the error on the form is still there.

Comment: can you try this in the conf file?   dbms.directories.plugins=plugins

Comment: i updated neo4j.conf to dbms.directories.plugins=plugins and restarted with 'sudo service neo4j restart'. but error is still there

Comment: i am still facing same error. apoc is not registered with neo4j community version. any clue ?

Comment: i don't know why this line (dbms.security.procedures.allowlist=) is missing in neo4j.conf file