# Neo4j Cypher, can't use apoc: There is no procedure with the name `apoc.help`

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

```
There is no procedure with the name `apoc.help` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.
```

There is another answer for this error message, but the solution does not work in my case.

Here are details that I think may be relevant, on Ubuntu 20.04.

```bash
sfarnsworth@ubuntu:~$ neo4j --version
neo4j 4.1.12

sfarnsworth@ubuntu:~$ ls /var/lib/neo4j/plugins/
README.txt  apoc-4.1.0.11-core.jar

sfarnsworth@ubuntu:~$ sudo neo4j restart

sfarnsworth@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf | grep apoc
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=my.extensions.example,my.procedures.*,apoc.*
dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=apoc.coll.*,apoc.load.*

sfarnsworth@ubuntu:~$ cypher-shell
neo4j@neo4j> call apoc.help();
There is no procedure with the name `apoc.help` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed
```

This happens for any apoc call that I attempt.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [APOC is only partially installing its extension in neo4j (one procedure)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42286508/apoc-is-only-partially-installing-its-extension-in-neo4j-one-procedure)

Answer (score 1):

What it seems to me is that you are not allowing `apoc.help()` in your whitelist definition. Try modifying the whitelist configuration:

```
dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=apoc.coll.*,apoc.load.*,apoc.help
```