# There is no procedure with the name `example.convertDirection` registered for this database instance

Tags: maven, neo4j, cypher, procedure, neo4jclient

I'm trying to create my own custom procedure using neo4J. I'm running the neo4j installer (v3.2.6) for windows.
I followed this [tutorial](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/neo4j-procedure-template) and created my own simple procedure below:

```
package example;
import java.util.List;

import org.neo4j.procedure.Description;
import org.neo4j.procedure.Name;
import org.neo4j.procedure.UserFunction;

public class ConvertDirection{

@UserFunction
@Description("example.convertDirection('v') - returns full direction name VERTICAL.")
public String convertDirection(
        @Name("string") String string) {
    if (string.equals(null)) {
        return null;
    }
    if(string.equalsIgnoreCase("v")){
        return "VERTICAL";
    } else if (string.equalsIgnoreCase("h")){
        return "HORIZONTAL";
    } else {
        return "BOTH";
    } 
}
}
```

I created my own test class and generated the jar running mvn clean package.

After that, I placed the procedure-template-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT in my both plugins folders (C:\Users\var\lib\neo4j\data\databases\graph.db\plugins and C:\Program Files\Neo4j CE 3.1.1\plugins).

Then I changed my neo4j.conf as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897634/there-is-no-procedure-with-the-name-apoc-help-registered-for-this-database-ins) to include the plugin paths. I've tried pointing both to program files/plugins and graph.db/plugins in both ways:

dbms.directories.plugins=c:/Users/var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db/plugins
dbms.directories.plugins=c:/Program\ Files/Neo4j\ CE\ 3.1.1/plugins

After restarting the server, I still got this error and my procedure isn't listed.

> There is no procedure with the name `example.convertDirection`
>   registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled
>   the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly
>   deployed.

Does anyone know what this might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a function, not a procedure (see `@UserFunction` in your code).

You should see it listed in `call dbms.functions()`, and as a function, CALL and YIELD are not needed, just use it inline like any other function.

Comment: Thanks for your help. In fact what I did was a user function.