# Apoc.algo.betweenness procedure not found: call apoc.help('algo') running

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

apoc.algo. betweenness procedure not found for me, ran following query similar to shown here on [github](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_betweenness_centrality_procedure) :

```
MATCH (o:Originator),(b:Beneficiary)
WITH collect(o) AS origs
CALL apoc.algo.betweenness(['LINKED_TO_ORIGINATOR'], origs, 'INCOMING') YIELD node, score
//Measuring shortest path between customers connected to each originator
SET node.betweenness = score
RETURN node AS originator,score ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 25
```

However, I get an error that the procedure is not found:
[image]
I ensured my conf file is well configured using stack overflow answers [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897634/there-is-no-procedure-with-the-name-apoc-help-registered-for-this-database-ins) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42286508/apoc-is-only-partially-installing-its-extension-in-neo4j-one-procedure)

Proof that call apoc.help('algo') is working:
[image]

Is the method apoc.algo.betweenness procedure removed from APOC library?

Alternately, I tried using apoc.betweenness but not sure how to set the relationship type as 'Incoming' and the node name (which of course is another question if this doesn't work). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 3.4 branch of the APOC source code contains the [Centrality](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/blob/3.4/src/main/java/apoc/algo/Centrality.java) class that implements the `apoc.algo.betweenness` procedure (annotated as `@deprecated`). But that class no longer exists in the 3.5 branch, so `apoc.algo.betweenness` is no longer supported in 3.5+.

However, the 3.5 Graph Algorithms plugin contains a number of [betweenness centrality](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/algorithms/betweenness-centrality/) algorithms. The names of those procedure start with "algo.betweenness". The linked documentation shows how to use them.